# Guzzle post gives me error 500, get works fine

Tags: php, curl, laravel-4, guzzle

I'm trying to build an API with api key and secret using laravel and guzzle. I am building both the api and the client using laravel.

I have a problem when I try to access a simple controller to get a json with a list of users from the database. It works fine when I'm not using the authentication, it fails when I do beacause I need to change to using post method so that the api gets the secret and the app_id:

```
GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ServerException (500)

Server error response [url] http://myapi.api/api/v1/users [status code] 500 [reason phrase] Internal Server Error
```

On  my client:

```
$_app_id = 'APP001';
$_app_key = '28e336ac6c9423d946ba02d19c6a2632';
$_api_url = 'http://myapi.api/api/v1/users';
$enc_request = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $_app_key, json_encode($request_params), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
$params = array();
$params['enc_request'] = $enc_request;
$params['app_id'] = $_app_id;

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$result = $client->post($_api_url, array(
    'body' =>  $params
));
$res=$result->json();  
var_dump($res);
```

On my API:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function(){
     Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
});
Route::filter('my.filter', function()
{
    $applications = array(
        'APP001' => '28e336ac6c9423d946ba02d19c6a2632', //randomly generated app key 
    );
    try {

        $enc_request = $_REQUEST['enc_request'];
        $app_id = $_REQUEST['app_id'];

        if( !isset($applications[$app_id]) ) {
            throw new Exception('Application does not exist!');
        }

        $params = json_decode(trim(mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $applications[$app_id], base64_decode($enc_request), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB )));

        if( $params == false ){
            throw new Exception('Request is not valid');
            $result['success'] = false;
        }else{
            $result['success'] = true;
        }

    } catch( Exception $e ) {
        $result = array();
        $result['success'] = false;
        $result['errormsg'] = $e->getMessage();
    }

    if($result['success']==false){
        return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        //I have tested and the APP never gets inside here, authentication is correct
    }
});
```

My controller:

```
class UsersController extends BaseController {
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::orderBy('username', 'asc');

        return Response::json(array(
            'error' => false,
            'users' => $users->get()->toArray()),
            200
        );
    }
}
```

If I remove the filter and simply change post to get on my client, I can see the json that comes from my users controller. As soon as I change it back to post, I get my error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changeing body to query and it worked fine as it was and could use the resource classes and guzzle at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Route resource uses the store method to post to the same uri as the index method. As stated within [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) and scrolling down to the 'Actions Handled By Resource Controller' part.

Comment: I need to be able to take advantage of the resource classes, my app will add/insert/select... using those urls, how can I make this work?

Comment: You can make this work by defining the route individually. But my advice would be to use the resource controllers as the documentation says, as this will lead to a more restful solution.

Comment: Yes, I get that, then how do you suggest that I make the authentication then for the api client? where should I do it if not in the filter?